# the following code is showing error while using in jupyter notebook

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network

from keras.layers import dropout

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 from keras.layers import dropout

ImportError: cannot import name 'dropout' from 'keras.layers'

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of tensorflow. If using tf > 2.0,
Use  `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` as the import statement,

If not, use `Dropout` instead of `dropout`